# Why calling different subscription on the same collection cause error in meteor?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I working on this [angular-meteor tutorial step 12](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/search-sort-pagination-and-reactive-vars)
an I have a question in

> **Stopping a subscription Topic**

you can use ctrl+f using "meteorSubscribe"

then the key sentence on that topic is

> The reason is that we are calling a different subscription on the same collection inside the partyDetails controller.

the code before correction is

```
$scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId).subscribe('parties');
$scope.users = $meteor.collection(Meteor.users, false).subscribe('users');
```

then after correction

```
$scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId);
$scope.users = $meteor.collection(Meteor.users, false).subscribe('users');
$scope.$meteorSubscribe('parties');
```

I try to run **before correction code** and nothing(error) show in cmd but it just cause the wrong result as tutorial say

> if you navigate to the party details page and then go back, pagination and search will stop working.

Then i got two question

1. Why no error show on cmd?
2. Why error from partyDetails controller affect to partiesList controller search and pagination? What is their relation?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: If you don't cancel a subscription, then if you navigate away and back again you will end up trying to subscribe twice to the same publication, resulting in the error, because subscriptions in meteor last until you end them.

There are two ways to get rid of a subscription with angular-meteor. One you can assign a handle variable to the subscription and then on navigating away from the page you can stop it. Two (the recommended way) is to use `$scope.$meteorSubscribe` instead of `$meteor.subscribe()` because it is set up to automatically remove the subscription when the scope is destroyed.

I can't see all of your code to know for sure why you are or are not getting the errors you think you should, hopefully this sheds some light on what is going on in the tutorial.

The very end result would be something like:

```
$meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
    $meteor.subscribe('parties', {
        limit: parseInt($scope.perPage),
        skip: parseInt(($scope.page - 1) * $scope.perPage),
        sort: $scope.sort
    }).then(function() {
        $scope.partiesCount = $meteor.object(Counts, 'numberOfParties', false);
        $scope.parties = $meteor.collcetion(function() {
            return Parties.find({}, {
                sort: $scope.getReactively('sort');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Notice that he's also changing the publish function on the server. It helps to understand if you click the links to show the git diffs.

Comment: @SarinSuriyakoon I edited my answer to hopefully shed some light on your problem.